# Ecommerce frontend split databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, database-design, web, architecture

Until now I've worked on a web app for keeping record of different products from different warehouses in regards to inventories and transactions etc.

I was asked to do an ecommerce front end for selling products from these warehouses and I would like to know how should I approach this problem?

The warehouses web app has a lot of logic and a lot of products and details and I don't know whether to use the same databases(s) for the second app by mingling the data in regards to user mgmt, sales orders and etc.

I've tried doing my homework but for the love of internet I don't even know how to search, if I'm placed on the right track I shall retreat to my cave and study.

I'm not very experienced in this matter and I would like to receive some aid in deciding how to approach the problem, go for a unified database or separated one-way linked datbases and how hard would it be to maintain the second approach if so?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of warehouses, I believe that is what you should do with your data, e.g. roll each and every disparate data source into a common set of classes/objects that your eCommerce store consumes and deals with.

To that end, here are some rough pointers:

1. Abstract logic currently within your inventory app into a middle tier WCF Service that both your inventory app and eCommerce app can consume it. You don't want your inventory app to be the bottleneck here.
2. Warehouse your data, e.g. consolidate all of these different data sources into your own classes/data structures that you control. You will need to do this to create an effective MVC pattern that is maintainable and sustainable. You don't want those disparate domain model inventories to control your view model design.
3. You also don't want to execute all of that disparate logic every time you want a product to show to the end user, so cache the data in a well indexed, suitable table as described above for high availability that you can get to using Entity Framework or similar. Agree with the business on an acceptable delay and kick off your import/update processes on a schedule.
4. Use Net.Tcp bindings on your services to move your data around internally. It's quick, it's efficient and there is very little overhead compared to SOAP when dealing in larger data movements.
5. Depending on scale required, you may also want to consider implementing a WCF Service purely for the back-end of your ecommerce store, that deals only in customer interactions with the underlying warehoused data sources, this could then warrant its own server eventually if the store becomes popular. Also, you could figure in messaging eventually between your SOA components, later down the line.
6. Profit. No, seriously!

I hope this helps. Good luck!